# Store and check multiple $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have 3 objects with same variable but rendered with diferent values.
`001 - Title  one`
`002 - Title  two`
`003 - Title  three`

I need to check on another block of page if this first three are the same. The only thing that comes to mind is store this variables in a `$_SESSION`. So far so good. The problem is that it only stores last value (obviously).

**CODE**

```
/* -- block one --*/
session_start();
$_SESSION['lasttitle'] = $item->getTitle;
echo $item->getTitle(); //rendering 1st object
echo $item->getTitle(); //rendering 2nd object
echo $item->getTitle(); //rendering 3rd object

/* -- block two --*/
session_start(); 
$last3 = $_SESSION['lasttitle'];
if($item->getTitle() != $last3) {
//don't render last 3
}
```

Comment: Store an *array* of the last three items...!?

Comment: Absolutely @deceze!!! But... how!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['lastTitles'][] = $item->getTitle();
$_SESSION['lastTitles']   = array_slice($_SESSION['lastTitles'], -3);

..

if (in_array($item->getTitle(), $_SESSION['lastTitles'])) ..
```

This stores an array of the last three titles, and checks whether a title is in this array.

Answer (score 0):

I think storing data as `array` in session might help you. Simply gather all titles you need in an array and put it into `$_SESSION` (instead of one variable). One the next page you will be able to analyze data you have and choose variables you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create multidimensional session:

```
$_SESSION['lasttitle'][$item->id] = $item->getTitle();
$_SESSION['lasttitle'][$item2->id] = $item2->getTitle();
$_SESSION['lasttitle'][$item3->id] = $item3->getTitle();
```

And check if that element is in array:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['lasttitle'][$item->id])) {
        $total++;
    }
}

if ($total == 3) {
    // Do something, it's all 3 titles in session!
}
```

I know it may be better solution, but I don't understand full algorithm. Also, to compare some arrays, you can use [`array_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: Note that `$item` and `$item2` or `$item3` are different variables. I cannot do in this way.